# WPF: Datagrid template column header does not accept "<" ">" symbol as value in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to Enter `< >` as name of the column header, but gives me error that `XML element is not closed`.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="<>" />
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape *<* sign so either

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn ... Header="&lt;>"/>
```

or

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn ... Header="&lt;&gt;"/>
```

will do